# What does "fatal objection" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across this phrase in Charles Darwin's *On the Origin of Species*:

> ON THE SUDDEN APPEARANCE OF WHOLE GROUPS OF ALLIED SPECIES: The abrupt
> manner in which whole groups of species suddenly appear in certain
> formations, has been urged by several palaeontologists--for instance,
> by Agassiz, Pictet, and Sedgwick, as a **fatal objection** to the belief
> in the transmutation of species. If numerous species, belonging to the
> same genera or families, have really started into life at once, the
> fact would be fatal to the theory of evolution through natural
> selection.

Am I correct to understand that "fatal" here means "critical" or "crucial"?

Comment: In the cited context, I'd say all three of "fatal", "critical" and "crucial" are effectively synonymous. What fine distinction do *you* think there might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Fatal" means "causing death". It means (metaphorically) that if these objections are valid, they would "cause the death of the theory", that is these objections could disprove Darwin's theory of the origin of species.

Darwin, being a scientist, presents all the potential objections, and then attempts to counter each one. Darwin continues in the section to justify why he believes that this is not a fatal objection.